# Can't get AddHandler and AddressOf to work with UpdatePanel

Tags: vb.net, button, updatepanel, addressof, addhandler

I am building a page that dynamically builds UpdatePanels, Panels, DDL, and Buttons. There is a single button for every UpdatePanel. I am doing some testing by trying to change a value after the button is clicked. As I step through the code after a button click the page loads and then calls the button click function. Yet it doesn't change the value of the Label I created.

```
Private Function BuildSaveButton() As Button
  Dim bt As New Button
  bt.CssClass = "saveButton"
  bt.Text = "Save"
  AddHandler bt.Click, AddressOf StateSaved
  Return bt
End Function

Private Sub StateSaved(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

  nameSelected.Text = "Worked!"
End Sub
```

Ideally what I am aiming for (because I have nested UpdatePanels) is for the page to only update what is in that specific UpdatePanel rather than the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm rather certain that you have to assign an owner to the control before adding the handler.

Since you're adding the button to a specific panel, just pass the panel in as a parameter.

I'm assuming that updatepanel is a class that you created which inherits form some class that utilizes the controls property.

```
Private Sub SubAddButtonToPanel(f as UpdatePanel) As Button
  Dim bt As New Button
  bt.CssClass = "saveButton"
  bt.Text = "Save"
  f.Controlls.Add(bt)
  AddHandler bt.Click, AddressOf Me.StateSaved
  Return bt
End Sub

Private Sub StateSaved(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

  nameSelected.Text = "Worked!"
End Sub
```

I have also added "Me."  in front of your call to StateSaved() as a precaution.

Comment: Don't forget to remove handler when disposing.